# What is the difference between .m and .mat files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, file-extension

When I traced my reference MATLAB script, I found files with the `.mat` extension. My questions are:

1. What is the difference between `.mat` and `.m` files?
2. How does one open files with the `.mat` extension?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Files with a .m extension contain MATLAB code, either in the form of a [script](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/scripts.html) or a [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html).

Files with a .mat extension contain [MATLAB formatted data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html), and data can be loaded from or written to these files using the functions [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) and [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), respectively. You can also access and change variables directly in MAT-files without loading them into memory using the function [`matfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html).

Comment: So .mat files are basically a holder for data which the .m script files use to do their bidding?

Comment: @KarlMorrison: Yes mat-files are the primary way to keep data persistent on the hard drive.