# cannot import matlab file to python code

Tags: python, matlab

I am on a project on machine learning. trained the data in matlab R2015a and obtained a file abc.m . I get the expected result from matlab file while giving input from the matlab command window. i have developed the interface in pyqt5 and got the file in python . Want to import .m file to python for usage.

have Anaconda 2.4.1 installed on my computer with python 3.5. 
working on Windows 8.1

Can anyone help ?
totally stuck with the project.

My code is as follows :

```
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np

from sklearn import preprocessing

ab = sio.loadmat('latest.m')
......
```

But i get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py",line 8,in <module>
 ab = sio.loadmat('latest.m')
 File "C:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py",line 58,in mat_reader_factory
 mjv,mnv = get_matfile_version(byte_stream)
 File "C:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\miobase.py",line 241,in get_matfile_version
 raise ValueError('Unknown mat file type,version %s,%s' % ret)
 ValueError: Unknown mat file type,version 111,114
```

Comment: It would be more helpful, If u paste code snippet tried by you and error it throw.

Comment: What does your file include? A script? A function? Your workspace?

Comment: my matlab file is 'latest.m'  .    python code : import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np

from sklearn import preprocessing

ab = sio.loadmat('latest.m') ..........................

Comment: But i get the following error : Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py",line 8,in <module> ab = sio.loadmat('latest.m') File "C:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py",line 58,in mat_reader_factory   mjv,mnv = get_matfile_version(byte_stream)  File "C:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\miobase.py",line 241,in get_matfile_version    raise ValueError('Unknown mat file type,version %s,%s' % ret)  ValueError: Unknown mat file type,version 111,114

Comment: Press 'edit' above (the link directly under your question text) and put your code into your question. You should format it as code. If you don't know how, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Code posted in comments is pretty much unreadable, and additional information that should go in your question should not be posted in comments.

Comment: Check first from matlab if you can load the file (`m = matfile(latest.m)`). Maybe you're not trying to load a valid mat file but the code (.m extension, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947549/what-is-the-difference-between-m-and-mat-files-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

[`loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) loads a MATLAB data file, e.g. the result of some code. MATLAB data files have `.mat` extension.

Loading a `.m` file means loading a bunch of text that doesnt mean anything without a MATLAB interpreter! What you want is to load a `.mat` file, a file containing matrices, strings or whatever it has been saved there.

**EDIT** I have just seen @valtuarte 's link to [What is the difference between .m and .mat files in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947549/what-is-the-difference-between-m-and-mat-files-in-matlab) . Have a check!